# Adding a library to a module using composer

Tags: 8, composer

I'm working on a module which will require a library that is already in composer.

I added a line to my module's composer.json file:

```
"require": {
   "markrogoyski/math-php" : "dev-master"
}
```

I ran the command:

```
composer update .
```

and a "vendor" directory was created in my module's directory and the files were downloaded.  However, If I add a use statement to the file my_module/src/Controller/Test.php I get an error:

```
----Test.php----

<?php
namespace Drupal\lims\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Math\Functions\Map\Single;

class Sample extends ControllerBase {
    public function content() {
        print_r(Single::square([1,2,3,4,5]));
    }
}
```

I see the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Math\\Functions\\Map\\Single' not found in [module path]/src/Controller/Test.php on line 9
```

Is there another step that I need to do to get the library autoloaded in the correct namespace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `composer update`, Composer created the vendor directory, and the autoload.php file, which is necessary to autoload the library. Unfortunately, Drupal doesn't load all the autoload.php files found in each of the directories containing a module.

Instead of adding the dependency of your module in the composer.json file used by Drupal, you should edit its extra/merge-plugin section to include the directory containing the modules you add.  (I added the *"modules/*/composer.json"* line.)

```
"extra": {
    "_readme": [
        "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
        "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php."
    ],
    "merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "core/composer.json",
            "modules/*/composer.json"
        ],
        "recurse": false,
        "replace": false,
        "merge-extra": false
    }
},
```

In this way, running `composer update` from the Drupal root directory would  add the required classes in the vendor directory used by Drupal, making them automatically loaded.

If the modules you install are all hosted on drupal.org (i.e., you don't use any custom module), you can instead edit the repositories section to contain the following lines.

```
"repositories": {
    "drupal": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packagist.drupal-composer.org"
    }
}
```

In this way, you could add a module hosted on drupal.org running `composer require drupal/module-name` from the Drupal root directory, and Composer would install its dependencies (declared in the module's composer.json file) in the vendor directory, making the classes automatically loaded.

Comment: There is also `mile23/drupal-merge-plugin` for helping with this. And if he module is hosed on drupal.org, then the composer.json of the module does not need any of that. And you can add the drupal.org composer repository `https://packagist.drupal.org/8`. Then a `composer require drupal/module-name` will work fine. Otherwise, the merge-plugin strategy above comes into play.

Comment: I should have been clearer: I am not saying to do both, but either one or the other, depending on where the modules are hosted.

Comment: Also, that plugin doesn't even have releases on [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/packages/mile23/drupal-merge-plugin). I would rather not use it.

Comment: Which "that plugin"? This exists for drupal-merge-plugin: https://packagist.org/packages/mile23/drupal-merge-plugin?

Comment: I see only a dev-master branch, for drupal-merge-plugin; there aren't versions.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you use the [Composer template for Drupal projects](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project):

1. In your custom module run `composer init` and then require a package/library.
2. In your Drupal project run `composer require wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin`.

   Then add the following to the `"extra"` array in your Drupal project's composer.json:

   ```
   "merge-plugin": {
       "include": [
           "web/modules/custom/*/composer.json"
       ]
   }
   ```

   (See docs on DO: [MergePlugin.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21wikimedia%21composer-merge-plugin%21src%21MergePlugin.php/class/MergePlugin/8.3.x).)

   (See [composer-merge-plugin](https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin) on GitHub.)
3. In your Drupal project run `composer update`.

   That's it.

Comment: Thanks @leymannx, your solution works for me!

Answer (score -1):

As per the documentation you will need to use the [dump-autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload) command to recreate the autoloader file.

Comment: I ran that command in the module root directory, and the response is: "Generating autoload files", and the file was still not found. I then tried running it in the Drupal Root directory, where the response was: "Generating autoload files
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::preAutoloadDump
> Drupal\Core\Composer\Composer::ensureHtaccess" and it also did not change anything. I cleared the Drupal cache each time.

Comment: You need to run the composer install/update/dump commands in the drupal installation root.

Comment: I got it to work by adding the require line to the drupal root composer.json file. Is there a way to add it to my module's file, and make Drupal know it's there and handle the dependency itself?

Answer (score -1):

You used well composer! The official MathPHP documentation says that you should use it like this:

```
use MathPHP\Functions\Map;
$x = [1,2,3,4];
$x² = Map\Single::square($x); // [1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Then you should not have trouble calling it from your controller. Try using "TestController.php" as filename and "TestController" as the class name. Helps the namespace.

I always use external libraries, oriented to DDD. You can see my [repository](https://github.com/jonathansanchez/Drupal8S3).

Comment: I am one of the developers of MathPHP. The root namespace was changed from Math to MathPHP at some point between now and when I asked the question.